# List all external assets in maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

Is it possible in maya to list all external assets being used in a file such as textures or other scenes being referenced?

Ideally this would be done using python. I'm more familiar with 3ds max, so Im not sure if maya has the equivalent of 3ds max where you can simply do this by the following...

Collect all assets of class type texturemap, which returns filepaths. Then collect all assets of class type xref, which returns referenced scenes and that's it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all referenced textures in the scene and then use : cmds.ls("REF_NAME:*", type="file")

To query all references : cmds.file(q=1,r=1)

---EDIT---
I had time to write a full code example :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import glob

files = cmds.ls(type=["file", "imagePlane"])
result = []
for i in files:
    if cmds.objectType(i) == "file":
        #animated ?
        testAnimated = cmds.getAttr("{0}.useFrameExtension".format(i))
        if testAnimated:
            # Find the path
            fullpath= cmds.getAttr("{0}.fileTextureName".format(i))

            # Replace /path/img.padding.ext by /path/img.*.ext
            image = fullpath.split("/")[-1]
            imagePattern = image.split(".")
            imagePattern[1] = "*"
            imagePattern = ".".join(imagePattern)

            # You could have done a REGEX with re module with a pattern name.padding.ext
            # We join the path with \\ in order to be Linux/Windows/Apple format
            folderPath = "\\".join(fullpath.split("/")[:-1] + [imagePattern])

            # Find all image on disk
            result+=(glob.glob(folderPath))
        else:
            result.append(cmds.getAttr("{0}.fileTextureName".format(i)))
    elif cmds.objectType(i) == "imagePlane":
        #animated ?
        testAnimated = cmds.getAttr("{0}.useFrameExtension".format(i))
        if testAnimated:
            # Find the path
            fullpath= cmds.getAttr("{0}.imageName".format(i))
            # Replace /path/img.padding.ext by /path/img.*.ext
            image = fullpath.split("/")[-1]
            imagePattern = image.split(".")
            imagePattern[1] = "*"
            imagePattern = ".".join(imagePattern)

            # You could have done a REGEX with re module with a pattern name.padding.ext
            # We join the path with \\ in order to be Linux/Windows/Apple format
            folderPath = "\\".join(fullpath.split("/")[:-1] + [imagePattern])

            # Find all image on disk
            result+=(glob.glob(folderPath))
        else:
            result.append(cmds.getAttr("{0}.imageName".format(i)))
#clear multiple instance
result = list(set(result))
```

Comment: How can i print the path's of the textures? So i can later edit them.

Comment: allTexures = cmds.ls(type="file")
for i in allTextures:
    fullpath= cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" %i)

Comment: Not really, if the item is using animated textures then you can not know the texture range

Comment: I forgot about this case, you can add  cmds.ls("REF_NAME:*", type="imagePlane") and cmds.getAttr("imagePlaneShapeNAME.useFrameExtension") and then use os or glob python module to find which file are on the disk. I'll add this above !